# objectliteral position is an instance of type?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-maps-api-3, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

In the below visualiation,

### [image]

object literal `geolocation` is under context of `navigator`(i.e., `navigator.geolocation`), but as per below code,

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript">
            </script>
            <script  type="text/javascript">
                    function showLocation(){
                        if(navigator.geolocation){
                            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
                        }else{
                            alert('geo location is not supported');
                        }
                    }

                    function showPosition(position){
                        console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(position));
                        var mapProp = {
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
                            zoom: 5,
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                          };                
                        new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
                    }
            </script>
```

---

```
<p> Click below to get your geo location</p>
        <button onclick="showLocation();">Click</button>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;border: 1px solid red;"></div>
```

---

Amidst debugging, `position` is an instance of type `Position` as shown below..

[image]

I could see `Position` neither in `navigator` nor in google api http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js

1) What is the context of `Position`(p in caps)? Is it a function constructor or object literal?

2) What are the list of members(like `coords`) in `Position`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be getting the google api mixed up with the navigator api, which is built into the browser. The position parameter being passed into your `showPosition` function, is not coming from google, thus would not be in the google api spec. So to answer your questions:

1) `position` not `Position` is an instance of Geoposition Constructor, which makes it an object.

2) `position` has the following members: `coords` & `timestamp`. `timestamp` is an number which represents the current time in milliseconds. `coords` is itself an Object (instance of Coordinates Constructor) which has its own members as follows: `accuracy`, `altitude`, `altitudeAccuracy`, `heading`, `latitude`, `longitude`, and `speed`.

Hope that helped.

Comment: But `Object.prototype.toString.call(position)` says `[object Position]`. Debugger also says the same.

Comment: That is odd, because doing the same thing in my browser, and in jsFiddle returns a different result: https://jsfiddle.net/qszvh88r/light/

You are unable to find the api's your looking for the wrong thing. in Mozilla, its called `Position`, in webkit its call `GeoPosition`. but its still the same. the input parameter is an instance of either constructor, but it would still have the same members I listed above. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Position

Comment: basically, as i said earlier, your confusing the google api with the navigator api. thus, your not able to find whatever it is that you are looking for. so, to answer your question explicitly, Position (capital p) is a Function constructor, while position (lowercase) is an instance of that Function.

Comment: I know that `Date` is a function constructor and I also know that it is `window.Date`.Can you answer now?

Comment: So, is your question, how can you access the `Position` constructor from the global scope? If thats the case, no.... there is no `window.Position`.  `Position` is a private member of the navigator geolocation api. when you call `getCurrentPosition` the browser, constructs an object literal for you on the fly and passes that into the function you provide it. If you would like access to the contructor itself, you can save it to a global variable by accessing the constructor through `position.constructor` and applying it to the variable of your choice.

Comment: `Position` is a private member of `navigator.geolocation`? But I see that `geolocation` is just an object literal with no members, when I type `navigator.geolocation`

Comment: `navigator.geolocation` IS an object literal, created from the `Geolocation` constructor. not sure what your knowledge of creating classes in Javascript is, but a private member is a value/function which is declared inside of the Constructor, but not applied to `this` which makes it not a member of the resulting object. people do this to hide the implementation of the function. Thus is why they've given you the `getCurrentPosition` function so that you may have access to the result of their implementation, rather than the constructor itself.

Comment: Can I get access to Geolocation function constructor code?

Comment: Because `Geolocation` is a native function, you cannot construct it through traditional means. It can only be created by the browser, through its own implementation.  you can see the problem if you put the constructo into a var like so `var geo = navigator.geolocation.constructor` and then try to call it as a new instance `new geo()`. what you should see is a type error telling you that it is native, and cant be implemented.

Comment: Can you please help me visualise? something like shown in this [diagram](https://github.com/shamhub/Javascript_Programming/tree/master/Topic7_OOJS/OOJS)